# Get all child comments ids from parent comment id

Tags: comments, sql

I want to get all child comments ids from parent comment id. Do i have to write custom sql 
or can i use get_comments() to achieve the following output.

eg 1

I want to get 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ids from parent id 1.

```
|- 1 (parent comment)
|-- 2 ( child of 1)
|--- 3 ( grand child )
|-- 4 ( child of 1)
|--- 5 ( grand child )
|---- 6 ( grand grand child )
|----- 7 ( grand grand grand child )
|------ 8 ( grand grand grand grand child )
```

eg 2

I want to get 5,6,7,8 comment ids from parent id 4.

```
|- 1 (parent comment)
|-- 2 ( child of 1)
|--- 3 ( grand child )
|-- 4 ( child of 1)
|--- 5 ( grand child )
|---- 6 ( grand grand child )
|----- 7 ( grand grand grand child )
|------ 8 ( grand grand grand grand child )
```

Comment: Hi guys no problem i solved it myself

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so that others can benefit and learn from it. :)

Comment: Why not deleting this kind of questions (*with a (kinda empty) comment as answer, which leaves other users still stare into the dark*)

Answer (score 4):

I found this post because I was looking for a similar solution.

As suggested by Captain47, get_comments with parent args, won't work because it's return only 1 level nested comments.

To get unlimited nested you need to use hierarchical arg as:

```
           $args = array(
            'parent' => $comment_ID,
            'hierarchical' => true,
           );
        $questions = get_comments($args);
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else trying to find this:

This can be done using the $parent parameter of [get_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

Here is the code assuming $parent_comment_id is the id of the parent comment.

```
$childcomments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id'   => get_the_ID(),
    'status'    => 'approve',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'parent'    => $question->comment_ID,
));
```

Now $childcomments will have an object with comment_ID as the ID of the comment. Refer to the '[Returns](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments#Returns)' of get_comment for details.

Hope this helps someone else searching for this.